# How can I re-instate Ctrl+D,C for the call stack window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'm running VS2012 Update 4, and ReSharper 9.2. I have chosen the VS shortcuts etc. in ReSharper, and on my menu, it still says that Call Stack is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>. Yet if I use that shortcut, VS duplicates the current line and adds a 'c' into my source.

How can I get this shortcut working again? Navigating the menus is really cutting into my efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resharper will map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to `ReSharper.Resharper_DuplicateText`. To re-map this, in Visual Studio go to `Tools`->`Option...`->`Environment`->`Keyboard`, type 'DuplicateText' in the 'Show commands containing:' text box, select 'Ctrl+D (Text Editor) from the 'Shortcuts for selected command:' and click the `Remove` button (or re-map it to another key combination).

Comment: Why does ReSharper do this when I tell it I want VS shortcuts etc? Some fail there.